# Docker error:" command not found"

Tags: docker

i use docker on windows. I'm just following some tuto for learn. When i use " FROM" or "apt-get" he say "command not found" i just try to "FROM ubuntu". Maybe cause of boot2docker ?

Thx a lot, much love.

Comment: you need to post the link of the tutorial you are following for the community to be able to help?

Comment: hi @maverick28 , i use a french tuto so i use the docker docs to explain u my probs : https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/ . I cant creat a " simple base image using scratch" cause i cant use from or add ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the repository https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world. It is mentioned in the documentation link which you are referring to start using docker for windows. Then you should use the Dockerfile in the repository and replace the COPY with ADD as mentioned in the commit message with the file on the repository link. That should enable you to use the base image. I hope it makes sense to you.